# Python 3.5: Normalize array results in TypeError

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of values between 0 and 255 (representative of one color channel of an RGB image). I want to normalize the array so that each image I'm working with appears to be the same brightness (or something along those lines). I'm applying the following function to each RGB channel (or rather each array in a x,y,3 dimensional array).

Function:

```
def normalizeRValues(self):

    for i in range(len(self.allImages)):
        arrR = self.allImages[self.imageKeys[i]]['R']
        arrR *= np.unit8(255)/arrR.max()
        self.allImages[self.imageKeys[i]]['R'] = arrR
    print("rNormalized")
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biegad1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "//mspm1bnas50s/home58/biegad1/Python Scripts/GUI_0_2.py", line 36, in getImgs
    self.organizedData = halThrThsnd.organizeAllData(self.imgArray, self.imagePaths)
  File "\\mspm1bnas50s\home58\biegad1\Python Scripts\SVM_0_3.py", line 89, in organizeAllData
    self.normalizeRGB()
  File "\\mspm1bnas50s\home58\biegad1\Python Scripts\SVM_0_3.py", line 72, in normalizeRGB
    self.normalizeRValues()
  File "\\mspm1bnas50s\home58\biegad1\Python Scripts\SVM_0_3.py", line 20, in normalizeRValues
    arrR *= np.uint8(255)/arrR.max()
TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float32') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

I initially thought I could fix the issue by casing `255` as an `uint8` but that didn't change anything except the first `dtype` in the error. If I don't include the cast, the last line of the error refers to a `float64` and when I include the cast, the last line of the error refers to a `float32`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT, READ THIS FOR A BETTER IDEA OF WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO: When I use the following function, I don't get a TypeError, but Python basically crashes (doesn't respond). I initially used this function but quickly stopped because it was clearly too inefficient. I'm including this script to give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

1st Script:

```
    for i in range(len(self.allImages)):
        arrR = self.allImages[self.imageKeys[i]]['R']
        meanRVal = np.mean(arrR)
        for index, value in np.ndenumerate(arrR):
            newRVal = (value - meanRVal) + 128
            arrR[index] = newRVal
        self.allImages[self.imageKeys[i]]['R'] = arrR
    print("rNormalized")
```

Comment: It seems arrR is float64 so you shoul look at the declaration of self.allImages and put dtype=np.uint8 as you are using up to 255. The hot fix is changing the cast from np.uint8 to np.. Or just write 255.0 instead of 255

Comment: @ElvisTeixeira `self.allImages` is actually a dictionary full of arrays. The arrays that I copy in are of type `uint8`. Would the type of those arrays change? I also already tried 255.0 and that created the same error.

Comment: Looks like division of `uint8` (even if both) results in a float. The error arise from trying to put that float back into a `uint8` array.  Try integer division (//) or use `astype` to cast the result back to `uint8`.